# Python opencv open webcam faster

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, usb-camera

I have a product need to open multiple cameras(about 20) with each camera capturing one single image. However, the time to initiate each camera takes about 3-4 seconds, and having all these time spent in sequence is relatively long.
So the question is: Whether there is a way to open a usb camera faster, and whether there is a way to do it in a concurrent way.
Appreciate any advice.

Thanks to everyone! I have code attached in below.

```
def take_picture(camera_id):
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
  cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
  res = None
  name = None
  while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret0, frame0 = cap.read()
    if frame0.any():
      real_location = 'station' + str(pos)
      name = real_location + '-' + 'collection' + str(cursor) + '.png'
      res = frame0
      break
  cap.release()
  return [name, res]
```

Comment: consider threading https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Maybe you could share with us how you open one camera?

Comment: open once, keep open. -- maybe you could explain what you are doing there and why. your approach might be far from optimal.

Comment: Thanks! I have the code attached.

Comment: As Christoph Rackwitz said, open once and keep the cameras open. You could save the frames every few seconds on the same image for each camera. So if you have 20 cameras you will have 20 updated images saved on the disk. So you can directly read the updated images on the disc whenever you want.